# Magento reindex does not populate solr search

Tags: magento, search, solr

We have solr installed as a tomcat application.  With the default installation of EE magento with sample data all runs perfect.

However, with a couple of our stores running the index does not touch the /solr/data folder.  Normally when a reindex is called all files in /data are cleared and repopulated.  However, on the live site this does not happen.

I have stipped back a lot of extesnions and run the index again.. this time the files are recreated but almost no data is captured... even less than the sample stores despite a much larger database.

Anyone any clues as to where we should be looking?

Comment: Worth asking in case someone knows the answers — but since you're using EE it may be worth burning a support ticket on.

Comment: 1.Try to access Solr using URL 
2.Check the files copy properly or not [ cp -R [your Magento install dir]/lib/Apache/Solr/conf/* . ]
3.From Magento Admin Panel test connection .

If you want a faster solution, download the solr folder from production and use this environment.